# When I want to create react app with yarn its give me this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

```
yarn : File C:\Users\TECH MOON\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this 
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn --v      
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: You need to change the power shell security settings to execute this script. Edit: the link you posted tells you the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Make sure you install npm and npx, then use create-react-app your app name.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).